# What font is used in this image

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What font is used in the following image (the target font):
[image]

I used multiple online tools, such as https://www.whatfontis.com and https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont, to find the matching font, but the closest I could find is Apple Chancery. I reproduced the above image by typing it in Apple Chancery, and I get the following:
[image]

This matches almost with the target font except:

- in the target font, the "t" in "chest" and "understand" has a tail that connects to the preceding "s"
- the "t" in these words is also more curved
- the cross stroke in the "t" in Apple Chancery is longer than the target font

Comment: The "st" is a ligature. It'll be a separate character on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Alt characters]
It *is* Apple Chancery but using alt characters. Apple Chancery has a lot of alternative characters and ligatures, they let you add or remove flourishes, here's a sample.

I'd stress that too much of this can look overcooked (even the top line looks a bit much to me), it's the kind of thing you have to use with restraint.

An alternative typeface with a good range of alt characters is [Poetica by Adobe](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/poetica-std) which is cross-platform and not just for Apple platforms. Also there is an [open-source type by Pablo Impallari](https://web.archive.org/web/20150801142101/http://www.impallari.com/media/uploads/prosources/update-38-source.zip) based on this style with tons of alts, he stopped working on it while it was in beta but it seems pretty much finished. It's more delicate with tall ascenders, it would work well for larger sizes. Or you could use [Requiem from Hoefler/Monotype](https://www.typography.com/fonts/requiem/overview) if you wanted an upright companion font in the same style. The general word for this style of typeface is "chancery italic".

I'm not a CSS expert but to activate ligatures [you use code like](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/open-type-syntax.html) `font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;`  and for swashes `font-feature-settings: "swsh";` . Font handling on modern apps treat these character variants as a way of styling text, not a separate set of characters, so that the underlying text isn't changed.

Comment: How would I add this alternate character/ligature?

Comment: You need an app that lets you choose alternative characters from a character map. I'm not sure what supports it, I'm away travelling and don't have a pro app to run tests with.

Comment: Thanks. Is this character/ligature also accessible programmatically? For example, would I use a escape sequence to add this character in a string in code?

Comment: What platform are you planning to use? Apple had a weird, Apple-specific architecture for complex fonts that never went cross-platform called TrueType GX, I'm not sure if Apple Chancery uses it or not. If so and you wanted to generate files programatically you might be better off getting a license to Adobe Poetica, which uses the standard cross-platform OpenType font format everyone uses.

Comment: I need to code this in Flutter. I have the TTF file. There should be common way to add this ligature to a string on any platform.

Comment: That's fine, Apple Chancery is bundled on iOS and macOS.  Apple doesn't sell Apple Chancery licenses so you won't be able to use the TTF in Android or Windows or web apps, you'd need to license another font (again, I recommend Poetica or Requiem). I don't know what support Flutter has for complex typography like stylistic sets and discretionary ligatures, you'd need to investigate that.

Comment: In general, if it supports HTML-based display of text that would be fine as modern HTML and CSS supports complex text features. But I'm not really a coder and I don't know Flutter at all, sorry. This is now becoming more of a font licensing and coding question than font identification, which moves away from my strong suit.

Comment: Sounds good. Is it possible for you to paste the text version of the text in your post with the ligatures so I could hack around and see what I can come up with? Could you also paste the text version of "chest" and "understand" with the ligature?

Comment: I've added some links about how to make it work above.

Answer (score 2):

ITC Zapf Chancery Italic. The connected letters are ligatures. In OpenType encoding there are five ligature sets, standard, discretionary, historical, contextual, and required. ITC Zapf Chancery supports standard and discretionary ligatures.

Standard ligatures are carried over from postscript encoding, which carried over from lead typesetting. Their purpose is to avoid collisions between letter pairs which otherwise would have overlapping parts. Depending on the typeface, the top hook of the "f" would intersect the dot of the "i", so the "fi" ligature was created. Other standard ligatures include "ff", "ffi", "ffl", "ft" and "fft".

Discretionary ligatures are more decorative than standard ligatures. These include “ck,” “ct” and “st”. These are some of the ligatures available in OpenType fonts:

[image: Table of standard and decorative type ligatures]

Comment: I tried ITC Zapf Chancery Italic [here](https://freefonts.co/fonts/itc-zapf-chancery-italic) and [here](https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-zapf-chancery/italic), and neither matches my target font.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Chancery with ligatures.

[image: Apple Chancery with ligatures]